# Hash table - issue with destructor (pointer being freed was not allocated)

Tags: c++, constructor, linked-list, hashtable, rule-of-three

I have a HashTable, where collisions are handled by chaining (linked lists). The first node of every linked list has a pointer from each array position. Shown below is a regular constructor along with rule of 3 functions.

Although my code is compiling and my functions (add, remove, etc) are producing the right output, I am having an issue with the destructor (the IDE points to it with a Thread 1: signal SIGABRT) and the console displays "pointer being freed was not allocated" after my driver program finishes running. I can't figure out what went wrong so any help would be appreciated. I did not include my code for any of the other functions (add, remove, etc) aside from constructors/destructors.

Even when I comment out the copy and overloaded= constructors, the same issue still arise with the destructor.

specification:

```
class HashTable {

public:

    HashTable(int);
    ~HashTable();
    HashTable(const HashTable &);
    HashTable& operator=(const HashTable &);

private:

    struct Node {
        string word;
        int wordCount;
        Node * next;

        // node constructor
        Node(string w, int count) {
            word = w;
            wordCount = count;
            next = nullptr;
        }
    };

    Node** wordList;
    int capacity;

    int hashFunction(string);
};
```

Implementation of big 4:

constructor:

```
HashTable::HashTable(int cap) {
    capacity = cap;
    wordList = new Node*[capacity];
    for (int i = 0; i < capacity; i++)
        wordList[i] = nullptr;   
}
```

destructor (where the problem seems to be)

```
HashTable::~HashTable() {
    for (int i = 0; i < capacity; i++) {
        Node* curr = wordList[i];
        while (curr != nullptr) {
            Node* prev = curr;
            curr = curr->next;
            delete prev;          
        }
    }
    delete[] wordList;
}
```

copy constructor:

```
HashTable::HashTable(const HashTable &obj) {
    capacity = obj.capacity;
    wordList = new Node*[capacity];
    for (int i = 0; i < capacity; i++) {
        if (obj.wordList[i] == nullptr)
            continue;
        Node * newNode = new Node(obj.wordList[i]->word,        
                                  obj.wordList[i]->wordCount);
        wordList[i] = newNode;
    }
}
```

copy assignment operator:

```
HashTable& HashTable::operator=(const HashTable &obj) {
    if (this != &obj) {
        for (int i = 0; i < capacity; i++) {
            Node* curr = wordList[i];
            while (curr != nullptr) {
                Node* prev = curr;
                curr = curr->next;
                delete prev;
            }
        }
        delete[] this->wordList;

        this->capacity = obj.capacity;
        this->wordList = new Node*[capacity];
        for (int i = 0; i < this->capacity; i++) {
            if (obj.wordList[i] == nullptr)
                continue;                
            Node * newNode = new Node(obj.wordList[i]->word,
                                      obj.wordList[i]->wordCount);
            this->wordList[i] = newNode;
        }
    }
    return *this;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your copy constructor and copy assignment operator, you are copying the list pointers from `obj` into `this`.  This leaves the same pointers in both objects, resulting in double free and other issues once one HashTable has been freed,

When you do the copies, you need to do a *Deep Copy*, which is to allocate new nodes for the copy of the word list.

Comment: Thank you! I did just that but now my code won't compile due to "Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x0)" error in the indicated line under my copy constructor.

Comment: I fixed that error by adding an if statement under each for loop in both copy and overloaded assignment constructors. But now I am back to the original error.